# Splitting field of the minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory, minimal-polynomials, roots-of-unity

I need a check for this:

> Let $n=2^p -1$, with $p$ prime and let $\alpha$ a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Show that $\mathbb{F}_{2^p}$ is the splitting field of the minimal poly $M_{\alpha^i}(x)$

---

I know that $$M_{\alpha^i}(x)=\prod_{j \in C_i}(x-\alpha^j)$$ where $C_i$ is the $i$-th cyclotomic coset. So it's a product of linear factors and since $\alpha$ is a primitive n-th root, it belongs to $\mathbb{F}_{2^t}$, where $t=ord_n(2)$. So I need to find the smallest $t$ s.t. $$2^p-1 | 2^t-1$$
and hence $t=p$. So $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{2^p}$. Hence $M_{\alpha^i}(x)$ is the product of linear factors like $(x - \alpha^j)$ and since they belong to $\mathbb{F}_{2^p}$, it is the splitting field, by definition

---

Is it okay, or am I missing something?

An easier way **that I don't want to use** would be to see that each cyclotomic coset has the same cardinality, which is exactly $p$. Hence, $M_{\alpha^i}(x)$ is an irreducible poly of degree $p$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Therefore, its splitting field is exactly $\mathbb{F}_{2^p}$.

Comment: You don't say so explicitly but is $p$ supposed to denote a prime?

Comment: Ups, my bad. Yes, $p$ is prime @DilipSarwate

Comment: @DilipSarwate in such a case, is everything okay?

Comment: I'm really sorry for bothering you, but could you please confirm if what I wrote is right? @DilipSarwate

Comment: The degrees of all the irreducible polynomial factors of $x^{2^m-1}-1$ are $m$ or divisors of $m$. Since $m=p$ is a prime, the only possible degrees are $m$ and $1$. So, $M_{\alpha^i}(x)$ is of degree $m$ except when $i=0$.